# issue with javascript condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fetching rank count from Html class and I want to show the result on base on rank count

there are 5 questions which  have these 4 options

which have Html like below

```js
var $ = jQuery;
var rank = 0;
 var i;
var x = $(".que").toArray();
var length = x.length+1;
for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {

  var rank_count = ($('.que' + i).find(".selected_answer").attr("class").split(/\s+/));
  //var rank = parseInt(rank) + parseInt(rank_count[1].replace('rank_',''));

  if (i == 5 && rank_count[1] == 'rank_1') {
    rank = parseInt(16);
    //console.log(rank);
  } else {
    rank = parseInt(rank) + parseInt(rank_count[1].replace('rank_', ''));
    //
    console.log(rank);
  }

}
// if rank between 0-4 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(0) && rank <= parseInt(4)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog1").css('display', 'flex');
}
// if rank between 5-8 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(5) && rank <= parseInt(8)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog2").css('display', 'flex');
}
// if rank between 9-12 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(9) && rank <= parseInt(12)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog3").css('display', 'flex');
}
// if rank between 13-16 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(13) && rank <= parseInt(16)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog4").css('display', 'flex');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="que1 que">question1</p>
<span class="answer rank_1">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2 selected_answer">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>


<p class="que2 que">question2</p>
<span class="answer rank_1 selected_answer">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>

<p class="que3 que">question3</p>
<span class="answer rank_1">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2 selected_answer">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>

<p class="que4 que">question4</p>
<span class="answer rank_1 selected_answer">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>

<p class="que5 que">question5</p>
<span class="answer rank_1 selected_answer">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>
```

in this, I have set condition if que5 has selected answer rank_1 then set rank 16 else rank count as per selected answer.

but when I set the selected answer as per

```
if (i == 5 && rank_count[1] == 'rank_1') 
    {
        rank = parseInt(16);
       console.log(rank);
    }else{
       rank = parseInt(rank) + parseInt(rank_count[1].replace('rank_',''));
       console.log(rank);
    }
```

it is not showing proper result or showing 2 result blog3 or blog4

I don't know why is this happen

can anybody help me with this

Comment: @connexo I have define `var rank = 0;` before for loop I am editing code

Comment: What is "i < length"?, length of what? and where is the length variable declared?

Comment: @TejiriAfe I have up-dated my code

Comment: In the code provided, there are no items with class `$(".que")` so your loop never runs.

Comment: What is $(".que").toArray();, you don't even have that class.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have updated my code

Comment: actually I have just given the example of that condition please check condition according to that

Comment: Some suggestions:  use `data-rank="1"` and `rank = $(this).data("rank")` to get the rank from the selected items - parsing the classnames is never a good idea (even if it worked) as they may change order and it's not semantically correct.  Second `$(".que .selected_answer").each(` is all you need

Comment: Tip: When you add a snippet, run it yourself to see if it works.  You've had to update multiple times based on our comments - when simply running it yourself before submitting would have saved a *lot* of time.  It **still** doesn't run in the snippet.

Comment: @MNJ Did you check answer below?

Comment: @as.if.i.code yes, thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes are needed at three places.
1. define length variable as `var length = $("p[class^='que']").length;`
2. In HTML < p >  tag should end after all span elements, only then `$('.que' + i).find(".selected_answer")` will be able to find span with .**selected_answer** class
3. condition inside **for** loop should include <= so that it reaches till 5

```js
//var $ = jQuery;
var rank = 0;
var length = $("p[class^='que']").length;

for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {

  var rank_count = ($('.que' + i).find(".selected_answer").attr("class").split(/\s+/));
  //var rank = parseInt(rank) + parseInt(rank_count[1].replace('rank_',''));
  
  if (i == 5 && rank_count[1] == 'rank_1') {
    rank = parseInt(16);
    
    //console.log(rank);
  } else {
    rank = parseInt(rank) + parseInt(rank_count[1].replace('rank_', ''));
    //
    console.log(rank);
  }

}
alert(rank);
// if rank between 0-4 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(0) && rank <= parseInt(4)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog1").css('display', 'flex');
}
// if rank between 5-8 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(5) && rank <= parseInt(8)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog2").css('display', 'flex');
}
// if rank between 9-12 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(9) && rank <= parseInt(12)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog3").css('display', 'flex');
}
// if rank between 13-16 then show this
if (rank >= parseInt(13) && rank <= parseInt(16)) {
  $('.result').find(".blog4").css('display', 'flex');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="que1">question1
<span class="answer rank_1">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2 selected_answer">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>
</p>

<p class="que2">question2
<span class="answer rank_1 selected_answer">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>
</p>
<p class="que3">question3
<span class="answer rank_1">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2 selected_answer">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>
</p>
<p class="que4">question4
<span class="answer rank_1 selected_answer">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>
</p>
<p class="que5">question5
<span class="answer rank_1 selected_answer">Simple Blog 1</span>
<span class="answer rank_2">Simple Blog 2</span>
<span class="answer rank_3">Simple Blog 3</span>
<span class="answer rank_4">Simple Blog 4</span>
</p>
```